# Comment an existing key-value pair in YAML file

Tags: python, pyyaml

I would like to know if it is possible to grab a key-value pair in a YAML file and then comment them out.

I have a code that reads a YAML file as txt and then inserts a `#` if `schedule:` exists. This un-schedules a job in our repo. My concern is that it's possible that a file may have the cron expression in another line:

`#schedule: * 3 * * *`

vs

`#schedule:
      - * 3 * * *`

I was wondering if there may be a way to load the file as YAML, locate the key-value (`{"schedule": "* 3 * * *"}`) and comment them out regardless of whether or not the key-value are on the same line or not. Other solutions are welcome too. I'm just hoping that I won't have to apply regex to this problem if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Why not read the yaml file into a dict, delete the `schedule` key and then dump into a new yaml file?

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r Will it not raise an error if only the value exists and no key?

Comment: How can a value exist without a key in a valid yaml file?

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r Oh, you mean that I delete the whole key-val pair? If so, I still want to save the cron expression because I am only temporarily un-scheduling the job. This is why I'm just looking to comment the `schedule` key-val pair.